# toJson method causing UI to freeze

Tags: java, android, gson

I have an ArrayList of objects that I am saving to SharedPreferences in my Activities onPause method. When I try to serialize it to json, I get the following in the logs (these 2 statements repeat and overload the logcat) :

```
06-20 20:33:31.620  26245-26252/com.example.app W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 21.556ms
06-20 20:33:31.620  26245-26260/com.example.app W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 5.901ms
06-20 20:33:31.650  26245-26260/com.example.app I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 210493(6MB) AllocSpace objects, 87(2MB) LOS objects, 25% free, 47MB/63MB, paused 16.970ms total 155.761ms
06-20 20:33:32.480  26245-26260/com.example.app I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 346396(10MB) AllocSpace objects, 140(4MB) LOS objects, 14% free, 48MB/56MB, paused 13ms total 88.199ms
```

I initialize the ArrayList in onCreate and then give it the objects when I am done executing an Asynctask. Here is the problem method that causes the UI to freeze:

```
  @Override 
  protected void onPause() {
  super.onPause();
  String json = mGson.toJson(mSelectedContactList);
  mSharedPreferences.edit().putString("contact_list", json).apply();
  }
```

I have also tried the following and continue to get the freeze up:

```
    JsonElement element =
    mGson.toJsonTree(mSelectedContactList, new TypeToken<ArrayList<ContactObject>>() {
    }.getType());
    String jsonString = element.getAsJsonArray().getAsString();
```

I know it is not the SharedPreferences that is the problem. I suspect the toJson method can't handle the process but I cannot figure out what is the problem here. Any help will be much appreciated.

***EDIT: Here is the class that I am using:**

```
public class ContactObject implements Parcelable {

// Instance variables
private String mID;
private String mNumber;
private String mName;
private boolean mHasPhoto;
private ArrayMap<Long, InboxSmsObject> mSentMessages;
private ArrayMap<Long, OutboxSmsObject> mReceivedMessages;
...
}
```

Comment: What's the size of the JSON you're serializing ? try using a contact list with only one element and see if it still gets stuck.

Comment: I am serializing an ArrayList of objects. I checked the size and it is only 7. I will try your suggestion of just adding one.

Comment: Whats the type of the objects in the array-list? you don't use generics by any chance, right? https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#toJson(java.lang.Object)

Comment: Just tried it with a single object in the list and it still froze up. It is a custom parcelable object.

Comment: Is it "freeze" as in app no longer responding (ANR) ? Or just stops for a while ? This depends on not just size but also the complexity of your object.

Comment: It is no longer responding to any touch events during this freeze and it eventually crashes due to ANR. My ContactObject has 6 member variables two of which are ArrayMaps. Would this be considered too complex?

Comment: Try to replace characters like '\n' , '\t' and etc with empty string after serializing to Json . It worked for me

Comment: The problem is that it never finishes serializing to Json. It gets stuck there.

Comment: Today I faced with a very similar issue, and I suspect that the protected `TypeToken` constructor is the reason. I also tried to reproduce it on a clean project, but it worked as expected. By the way, did you manage to overcome the issue? Perhaps the `TypeToken` was the reason as well and it hanged up?

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem. I could almost guarantee that the problem is due to the fact that GSON is having a hard time serializing either your InboxSmsObject or OutboxSmsObject object. Your ContactObject class looks simple, but you have to keep in mind that GSON will also have to serialize the objects in the ArrayMap.

The first thing you should do is to try to change one or both of these classes inside your ContactObject class to some simple class like String. I would be will to bet that the serialization works in this scenario.

Once you have confirmed that this is indeed the case, then you can work on a solution. The solution I employed was to create a simple class with just the settings required to construct the InboxSmsObject. For instance, create a class called InboxSmsObjectSettings which has only the essential information required to instantiate the InboxSmsObject class (I would guess that this class only needs a few Strings). Then create a constructor like

InboxSmsObject( InboxSmsObjectSettings settings )

so that you can easily instantiate the InboxSmsObject from the settings. I know that this isn't the best solution since you will have to recode some stuff, but it worked for me.

Comment: I do not agree Eugen. If he is trying to perform something when the Activity is shutting down, then he should be doing it on the main thread. If you do it off of the main thread, you would not be guaranteed that the serialization would finish before the new Thread is cleaned up. I tried to do what you suggest, and have repeatedly seen Android kill my serialization thread prematurely. This occurs, for instance, if the user swipes the process from the recent apps list. The only way to ensure that the serialization occurs is to make the task as small as possible, and to do it on the main thread.

Comment: That's why we don't just spawn threads as we like but use Android specific tools such as [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) which **a)** is independent of the activity **b)** executes on a worker thread.

Comment: If you are getting the errors that Jose is getting AND the Activity is being paused because the user has swiped the app from the recent apps list (which will ultimately kill the process), then it does not matter if you run the code in a thread, AsyncTask, foreground service, or worker thread inside a service... Android will kill it before it finishes and you will continue to see these errors. Both the Service and Activity live on the same process (unless you modify the manifest), so if the process is being killed, then you simply need to make the class simpler. I tried before posting my answer

Answer (score 0):

That can be a recursive issue.

Please, check if you've recursive models, for instance:

```
public class ClassA {

   ClassB b;

}

public class ClassB {

   List<ClassA> aList;

}
```

Comment: Not really. Having recursive relations would lead to stack overflow rather than freeze. Today I faced a similar issue, but probably originated from another reason, and I really doubt it's because of this.

Answer (score 0):

One of possible reasons of the issue is ProGuard-ing over type tokens, probably when the obfuscation is not suppressed. I had a very similar issue too, and the overall scenario was:

- There was a simple outer package-visible class containing `TypeToken` instances only, thus being a type token registry in order not to instantiate type tokens every time I need deserialization. Worth to note (but does not really affect the case), the type tokens were exposed as package-visible static final fields.
- There was a deserializer that referenced the registry. Once the very first deserialization is executed (thus *referencing the type tokens registry class*), the application UI thread freezed until the device asks that the application is frozen asking to stop it.

I did not notice immediately that the static field initializers was the reason of the freeze. After some debugging I realized that some constructor in the abstract `TypeToken` class causes the hang. That's why just a simple accessing a static field caused the application to freeze. I cannot really recall which constructor causes it, but I would claim that GSON type tokens may run into an infinite loop somewhere in its internals if your type tokens parameterization is erased during ProGuard-ing. So just re-configuring ProGuard fixes the issue:

```
-keepattributes Signature
```

See more for [ProGuard Attributes](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/attributes.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a constructor for ContactObject just remove it. It should work fine afterwards.